# C# Converting a console app to Windows Forms app and display the console messages

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

If I have a simple console app like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    FeedCat();
    FeedDog();
}

public static void FeedCat()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get cat food");
    Console.WriteLine("Feed cat");
    Console.WriteLine("Meow");
}


public static void FeedDog()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get dogfood");
    Console.WriteLine("Feed dog");
    Console.WriteLine("Woof");
}
```

Now I simply to turn this console app into a windows app where there is a **Start button** and **Text Display**.

- Start button - simply just call the method that contains `FeedCat()` and `FeedDog()` and run them.
- Text Display - Multiline, read-only, display all the `Console.WriteLine` messages.

So what should I replace `Console.WriteLine` with?

I tried this but it doesn't work - nothing shows up in the text display.

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox displayBox;
    public string displayMsg
    {
        get { return displayBox.Text; }
        set { displayBox.Text = value; }
    }

static void Main()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1);
}

public static void FeedCat()
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.displayMsg += "Get cat food";
    f1.displayMsg += "Feed cat";
    f1.displayMsg += "Meow";
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Simply drag and drop a textbox from toolbox and `displayBox.Text ="any text"` and done

Comment: That part is already done. But I can't just call `displayBox.Text` directly from other class.

Comment: In your sample the code for the button press event is missing. Did you add it? Anyway, the best way to know why it's not working is debugging your application, have you done it?

Comment: Yea they are actually there, app can be debugged and run except those messages won't show up. The problem here is because I instantiate a new `Form1` in my `FeedCat()` method, meanwhile when I run the program, there is this `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1);`. So it's essentially two different `Form1`.

Comment: You are right, you are creating a new Form. It should be just `this.displayMsg="Get cat food"...`

Comment: Or,if you really want another form, you should at least show it `f1.Show();`

Comment: Post the complete code with click events and other things.